# Laravel php multiple JsonSerializable

Tags: php, json, laravel, doctrine-orm, json-serializable

I have complex object Model, with composition of other objects, and I use JsonSerializable in each of them.
Let take simplified example:

```
class CarPark implements JsonSerializable
{
   /** @var array|Car[] */
   private array $cars;
...
   public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "title" => "My cars",
            "cars" => $this->cars
        ];
    }
}

class Car implements JsonSerializable
{
   private string $model;
   private string $year;
...
   public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            "model" => $this->model,
            "year" => $this->year,
            "price" => $this->calculate()
   
        ];
    }
   private function calculate():string {
...
   }
}
```

For API I just do `return new JsonResponse($carPark);` and get nice json.
I want to save this object in DB as json, but I dont want to save `'price'` value.

My question is:
How to make my object for API pass one json structure and for db another json structure?

P.S. For Laravel DB ORM I use Doctrine.

Comment: Can't you just create a `toDbJson` function on the `Car` model in which you can the `toArray` function, remove any key you don't want, than serialise the array to JSON?

Comment: Maaren Veerman,yes I did  the way you suggested. But you have to foreach all object inside other object, and it is not very nice thing. So I was wondering is there any other way to do it?